# Load speed difference between Wireshark and tshark

Tags: wireshark, tshark

I have some PCAP files from which I'm trying to extract metadata. I am doing this using tshark, opening the file, extracting a couple dozen fields, then writing the table to disk. I've noticed that this process can be pretty time consuming, sometimes up to 30 minutes for a single PCAP file. I am performing reverse DNS on the data, using the default settings (`-N dmN`) and I have the same reverse DNS settings in Wireshark. I understand that reverse DNS is a fairly time-consuming process relative to other processes that tshark/Wireshark is performing. However, when opening the same file in Wireshark and in tshark, Wireshark loads the file in a matter of seconds, while tshark will take minutes. My tshark command is:

```
tshark -r my_pcap_file.pcap \
    -2 \
    -T fields \
    -E separator=/t \
    -E header=y \
    -E quote=d \
    -e frame.time_epoch \
    -e frame.len \
    -e frame.protocols \
    -e _ws.malformed \
    -e _ws.col.Protocol \
    -e _ws.col.Length \
    -e ip.rec_rt \
    -e ip.src \
    -e ip.dst \
    -e ip.src_host \
    -e ip.dst_host \
    > my_pcap_file.tsv
```

Is there a known reason for this speed difference?

Comment: I might be wrong, but Wireshark might not load the entire data at once, but loads it dynamically as you scroll down. What's the size if your PCAP file? I've never noticed any performance issues with `wireshark`, and I used it on pretty large files. Also, `-N dmN` is not the default and it actually **disabled** reverse DNS resolution (you'll need an additional `n` for enable it - `-N dmNn`). What's the difference between using it with/without reverse DNS (add `-n` instead of `-N dmN`)?

Comment: I also wonder if the slowness is caused by writing the data to the disk (which Wireshark doesn't do and just loads everything to the memory). How long does the `tshark` command take when you don't write the data to disk (redirect it `/dev/null`) compared to writing it to the disk?

Comment: Please post the result of a couple of consecutive *time tshark blahblah* (as /usr/bin/time to get the GNU version) using default format string and taking care your system is not heavily loaded.

Comment: @aviro from what I can tell `-N dmN` is the default. From the tshark manual page: "If both -N and -n options are not present, the values from the preferences are used, which default to -N dmN." Maybe I'm misunderstanding that statement? I've run a few pcap files with /usr/bin/time, directing the output to `/dev/null`. The resulting file sizes and timing outputs are: {20.7 MB: 6.16user 3.51system 11:36.95elapsed 1%CPU, 10.2 MB: 2.18user 3.28system 10:45.22elapsed 0%CPU, 42.1 MB: 6.70user 5.13system 44:07.60elapsed 0%CPU}

Comment: I re-processed the last file in the previous comment, and while the timing decreased, it was still quite long: 6.73user 4.66system 32:31.08elapsed 0%CPU